# What is the best practice for sharing frequently used components in Angular 4+?

Tags: angular, angular-components

My Angular application is setup with Angular routing and displays different components based on the URL. The templates for header, navigation, footer and commonly used modals are defined in the root app template. The `<router-outlet>` tag is provided here as well.

What is the best practice for sharing the components declared in my root app template with the various components that will be loaded within the `<router-outlet>`? For example, assume that the following template is my root template:

```
<header-component></header-component>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer-component></footer-component>
<loading-dialog-component></loading-dialog-component>
```

Components Component1 and Component2 are loaded using routing specified in my module declaration as such:

```
appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'component1', component: Component1 },
{ path: 'component2', component: Component2 }
];
```

I would like to access the `<loading-dialog-component>` from within Component1.component.ts as well as Component2.component.ts. What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: When you say "access", what exactly is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Create a shared re-usable ngModule